# Como posso substituir esta expressão regular utilizando o Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Atualmente eu utilizo esta expressão para extrair tudo o que está abaixo da tag `<b>` até encontrar outra tag `<b>`:

```
blocks = re.findall(r'<b>.+?<b>', str(element))
```

Como eu posso fazer a mesma coisa utilizando o Beautiful Soup?

OBS: o arquivo HTML não está estruturado, e eu recebo ele bagunçado de várias maneiras diferentes, por isso queria algo que funcionasse para todos os casos.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<html><head><title>Pegar conteúdo da tag b</title></head>
<body>

<b>Teste 1</b>
<b>Teste 2</b>
<b>Teste 3</b>

</body>
</html>

"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
lista = soup('b')
print(lista)

for item in lista:
    print(item.string)
```

Resultado:

```
python3 conteudo_b.py 
[<b>Teste 1</b>, <b>Teste 2</b>, <b>Teste 3</b>]
Teste 1
Teste 2
Teste 3
```